# How do I package fonts along with a .cls for CTAN

Tags: fonts, ctan

I am currently doing this to load a local font into a tex document:

```
\newfontfamily{\notoheb}{hebrew}
[Extension = .ttf]
```

I would like to package this up and put it on CTAN, but I have like 100 fonts I want to include in the package. Is there a way I can make it so the package can lazily download the fonts as they are used in some document? Is there a way to install them globally so they don't need to be local like this? How do I do that?

[Here](https://ctan.org/help/upload-pkg) they say just to include everything in a zip. But it would be very large. Is there a better way to do this? Can I reference the font remotely perhaps, like this?

```
\newfontfamily{\notoheb}{https://mywebsite.com/hebrew.ttf}
```

Comment: I would not say you should write a class file for this. A package file `.sty` would be more appropriate.

Comment: The problem is not so much the number of fonts (the noto fonts are over 100 fonts too), but the license of the fonts. Are you sure that you can upload everyone to ctan and that it is free for use?

Comment: Yes I am sure :)

Comment: Unless you plan to make the fonts usable in `pdftex` or to provide a means of doing something especially clever with the fonts, what’s the point of packaging them? Interested parties will already have installed them and will see their disk space wasted by duplicate copies in TeX Live, no?

Comment: I take it you are using \RequirePackage or something to that effect.  You could create an ASCII file containing a list of all the packages you want, load the first and rewrite the file containing only the remaining packages.  After 100 runs they will all be loaded (on the hard drive).

Comment: Are you sure you're allowed to redistribute all those fonts in that way? Also, personally, I'd not like a package/class like that on CTAN, my TeXLive installation is large enough... :)

Comment: I'm surprised at how many limitations there are with CTAN, why doesn't it just work like any other package manager like NPM for example? Anyone is allowed to host anything, why the restrictions on CTAN?

Comment: for tex-specific fonts really they need to be packaged via ctan/texlive/miktex etc, but for ttf it is really just as convenient to just make the ctan tex package the tex support and arrange that people install the ttf fonts directly into their system as that is often more convenient as it makes them available to more systems but is hard to organise in a cross platform ctan package.

Comment: what ctan restrictions are you referring to? There are very few restrictions on what may be posted to ctan. saying it works like "any other package manager" is a bit funny given the history. as it is almost certainly the oldest software archive network, older than CPAN etc.

Comment: I see you are suggesting notoheb as the name, are they these fonts? https://www.google.com/get/noto/#serif-hebr

Comment: Yeah these are just examples, I am not going to use the noto fonts in my case.

Comment: @LancePollard but the same applies, if they are generally usable ttf fonts I would just make the tex package the _tex support_ for the fonts and leave it to other distribution mechanisms to get the fonts installed as system fonts in windows/mac/linux/whatever.